# Controlling aspects of a button from another button press - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

[image: What I want to do]

I want to be able to change the background color of the removeButton when I press the resetButton. I don't have much of an idea for what to do and google wasn't finding anything

And if I'm doing anything not great in Swift syntax, lemme know, as I'm new to the language

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the remove button to create an outlet like

```
@IBOutlet weak var removeButton:UIButton!
```

then do this inside the resetButton's action

```
removeButton.backgroundColor = .red
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.        Should I look at the @IBOutlet line as the creation of an object and the removeButton as the object name?

Comment: IBOutlet means it's object created in IB and yes removeButton is the object name

Comment: Think of an `@IBAction` as a verb. It's an action (method) that gets triggered when you interact with a view. Think of an `@IBOutlet` as a noun. It's a reference to a view so you can make changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get referance for removeButton. Just like you created IBAction for removeButton, create IBOutlet of removeButton. Then in resetButton function just change background color of removeButton

```
removeButton.backgroundColor = .red
```